# No puedo debuggear con la extension de Debugger for Chrome en VSCODE

Tags: python, django, reactjs, ubuntu, vscode

Recien me pase a Linux Ubuntu por necesidades del sistema que estoy realizando, pero en Windows usaba la extension de Debugger for Chrome en el proyecto realizando con YARN.

Ahora lo instale en ubuntu , pero al intentar el Launch. me envia el sig. error.

[image: He cambiado el url a 3000 porque inicio el proyecto en ese puerto , a]

Answer (score 0):

Las instrucciones salen en la página del proyecto [`vscode-chrome-debug`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#attach).
Para linux, debes ejecutar chrome en modo de depuración como:

```
google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Comment: Gracias Alter Lagos, no funciono eso para mi, la solución fue el magico "Reinicio" ,el vsCode dejo de mostrar el error, encontre que es un problema de WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux ).